# Ionic 4 and using material tabs router outlet

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular-material

I am wanting to use Material Tab's (https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api#MatTabLink) within my Ionic 4 project, now, the requirements are that I need to house multiple views in a tab and the first thought was that I can use a new `ion-router-outlet` or `router-outlet` within my parent component.

Bare in mind that I do already have one router outlet for the main app.

I am lazy loading the main chat routes in my **app-routing.module.ts**, this page is responsible for loading the tabs.

```
  { path: 'chat', loadChildren: './chat/chat.module#ChatPageModule', canActivate: [ AuthGuard ]}
```

Now, in my **chat.module.ts** I have the following routes:

```
{ path: '', component: ChatPage },
{ path: 'active', component: ActivePage },
{ path: 'messages', component: MessagesPage },
{ path: 'teams', component: TeamsPage }
```

`ChatPage` component is my parent tab view page. The others I am wanting to be in a tab.

The HTML for displaying these tabs is in `chat.page.html` and looks like this:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
        <a mat-tab-link
            *ngFor="let link of routeLinks"
            [routerLink]="link.path"
            routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
            [active]="rla.isActive">

            {{ link.label }}
        </a>
    </nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I have also tried `<ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>` but this throws up more issues.

The main issue here is that the routes look as though they are loading up in the main router outlet rather than the child one, I have tried adding the name attribute to the mark up but my IDE states that it's not valid and doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have figured it out, and I am going to look stupid for not trying this before but the issue was that in order to use this child router-outlet the routes I wanted in tabs need to child routes.

```
{ path: '', component: ChatPage, children: [
            { path: 'active', component: ActivePage },
            { path: 'messages', component: MessagesPage },
            { path: 'teams', component: TeamsPage }
        ] },
```